# Use two different databases in one project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to use two different databases for the same project in Ruby On Rails?

At the moment I use PostgreSQL with Heroku for my project and I would like to use Redis to store some of my models.

Thanks

---

First step, add redis-rb to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'redis', '2.1.1'
```

Then install the gem via Bundler:

```
bundle install
```

Lastly, create an initializer in config/initializers/redis.rb and add the following:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

Will that have any side effects to my existing database PostgreSQL database?

Or I 'll able to use $redis whenever I want to store something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the steps you've written, you shouldn't have any problems with ActiveRecord/Postgres

`$redis` will work fine for you, as long as the connection works.

Comment: Rails will not try to migrate all my models to Redis database right?

Comment: No, it won't do anything like that, unless you make it do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Redis as a database storage for your model then you should use some of the available gems that lets you easily store objects in Redis. Some of the gems are:

- [OHM](https://github.com/soveran/ohm)
- [Redis::Objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects)

Comment: But that's the point I do not want Redis as a database storage. I just want to store part of the project's database

Comment: Then you should change the title and context of your question ;)