# Ruby on Rails two completely different databases on the same project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, sqlite

I spent last couple of hours searching the web for this solution and I didn't find any, so I wanted to ask here if anyone has experience with something like this.

I started working on a very big Rails project and I've got some very strange request from the project manager.

He wants me to use 2 different MySQL databases for different environments (which I already found how to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311199/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-ruby-on-rails)

Apart from this he wants to make a small local database which would serve as an autosave vault for the recent documents (maybe 5-10 recent documents) and he wants this database to be a SQLite.

Since I just started with the Rails recently I didn't even know if this sort of connection is possible, and is something like this even possible in Rails.

I also thought of using a [Connection Pool](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) to ensure thread safety.

Any advice and help is appreciated.

Comment: it should be possible yes. Are the 2 MySql databases completely different things, or are the contents of them similar to the point where you would dynamically select between the two? Is the local database taking the 5-10 most recent things gotten from either of the MySql databases?

Comment: Have you seen this [Blog Post](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/09/21/establishing-a-connection-to-a-non-default-database-in-rails-3-2-2/) while it is from 2012 the functionality and advice remains true.

Comment: @Clark it should dynamically set between the two, and it's not taking any data from MySQL databases, but application should write directly into it (Though I don't know if it's a smart idea). Engineer - thank you for the tip, I haven't actually seen that blog post :)

Comment: For a good place to start I would look at these answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808645/use-two-different-databases-in-one-project